# Can commercially sold, vacuum-packed beetroot (cooked) be stored under room temperature?

Tags: food-safety, storage-lifetime, vacuum, beets

I don't have any experience at all with beetroots. But a couple days ago, I received some vacuum packed cooked beetroots by post (without special temperature control) as part of a vegetable basket.

They had no instruction printed on the package so I didn't put them in the fridge. Today I went to the supermarket and saw they are actually sold in the chilled section (as with milks and salads).

In general, are they safe to be stored in cool room temperature (20-21 C) for a few days? Or is there a difference between packaging that makes some okay but not others?

Comment: Did the packaging say anything?  Because I know in the US, there are some things that are sold in the refrigerated section that don't actually need to be refrigerated.  (like some plant milks that are UHT pasteurized ... but they put them in with all of the other milk as it gives the illusion of freshness.  And it keeps you from having to look in different sections for things)

Comment: I know the vacuum packed cooked beets in my store are sold unrefrigerated. I don't know if this generalises though.

Answer (score 5):

Forgot to update.

They went bad (blew up actually) after a week or so, when the expiry date on the packet is months away.

So at least in my case, some beetroots in vacuum packaging should be stored in the fridge, although there are beetroots that can be stored room temperature (which I saw in another market).

You should probably err on the safe side if you find no instruction on the package (like in my case).

Answer (score 1):

A lot of vacuum-packed things are pasteurized and will be shelf-stable. In general, though, raw vegetables will not be. Raw beetroot, like other root vegetables, will [last for a shockingly long time if kept at low temperatures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_cellar), but at room temperature it'll behave like other vegetables and rot after a few days.